# what will be the excel vba code to get the values from .INI file?

Tags: excel, vba, ini

I have an INI file. Now i want to parse that file in excel vba. the code must be worked in excel 2010 or higher version. I tried on google to get the code for this problem but no one can understand full functionality of that code. So please tell me the code to parse the INI file and also give me overview what is actually happening in the code.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Please read the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article to help us help you. Your question is too broad.

Comment: please show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing files in VBA is not a beginner's task.  If you'd like to learn to code there are a lot websites with basic tutorials to get you started.

Whatever it is that you need to get out a .INI file, you can do with Excel, about eight different ways, any of which are going to easier on you.

To open the INI file in Excel, just:

> Right Click the file → Open With → Excel.

If you need any "parsing" beyond Find (CTRL+F), Copy (CTRL+C) and Paste (CTRL+V) for such a basic filetype, Google "Excel text functions" for some ideas.

Good luck!

Comment: I want to parse the values and used that keyvalues in my excel code in different modules.

Comment: `used that keyvalues in my excel code in different modules`  In different modules?  Did you mean different _workbooks_?  Can you provide an example of how you need the data parsed?  Is this for only one INI, or multiple from multiple applications?  What is the purpose? Is it a one time parse job or would it be executed regularly?   Are there any similar existing utilities (or code) that are suitable or that could be adapted?